# Pass big string in asp net and get answer using json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to pass a big string in my controller using json. Also i need Controller to send me an answer.

Here is my controller in web api:

```
public class CustomersController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Customers
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/Customers/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST: api/Customers
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT: api/Customers/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE: api/Customers/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

First of all where i should read my string and where should i send an answer?

And here is my client which try to send a string

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://192.168.1.15:8282/",new StringContent("Mystring", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
          string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

I need my web api to read my string, and then to send me an answer

Comment: A good start would be not making your controller methods `void`. Have you found some examples or tutorials?

Comment: Do you mean in post method?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure what version of MVC/Web API you are using but I would encourage you to [do some self learning](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: There are thousands of examples online. Any tutorial on Web API will have this covered as the first lesson.

Comment: I really searched very much tutorials in internet, but i can't find anything. Maybe i'm searching in wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the methods as `void` you need to `return` the string value from the controller methods.
Also, don't forget to decorate the methods with respective http verb attribubte (`HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut` etc.) which the method is responsible to serve.

Here's an example where the method returns an Ok result, this generate an http status code 200 with the string in the response body

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    return Ok(value);
}
```

Then for the client call.
First of, you need to specify the route to the controller correctly

```
192.168.1.15:8282/api/Customers
```

Then, sending a single string as content when using the content-type of `application/json` is not suitable as json always start parsing from an object `{}` or array `[]`.
The easiest way of sending a single string is therefore to just change the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and adding a `=` sign infront of the string

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://192.168.1.15:8282/api/Customers",new StringContent("=Mystring", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, but my client doesnt seem to send anything...Post reads null from my http client

Comment: @Dim looks like your url is wrong, try with http://192.168.1.15:8282/api/Customers, updated the answer

Comment: Now server it answers me, but i'm  getting null

Comment: @Dim Updated the answer